# Setting ValidationGroup on RequiredFieldValidator from a property isn't setting correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net, properties, requiredfieldvalidator

I am trying to set my required field validators ValidationGroup dynamically from a property on my page however they are not firing. If I set the string manually it fires. My assumption is that its not pulling the property properly into the ValidationGroup. Am I missing something?

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="rfvHouseName" ControlToValidate="txtHouseName" ErrorMessage="Please enter a house name/no." ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="<%#ValidationGroup%>"><i class="fa fa-star requiredFieldStar"></i></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtHouseName" runat="server" MaxLength="50" CssClass="form-control" />

private static string _validationGroup = "NewAddress";

public virtual string ValidationGroup
{
    get { return _validationGroup; }
    set { _validationGroup = value; }        
}
```

Comment: Is the Properties of the _ValidationGroup and the getter and setter in the class of the code behind?

Comment: Yes. I can step into it. If I put a <%= ValidationGroup%> on the page then it displays the expected string.

Comment: would spaces help like this '<%# ValidationGroup %>'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set it in code behind

```
rfvHouseName.ValidationGroup = ValidationGroup;
```

Or if you really want to use it inline, you have to use it like this

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ValidationGroup='<%# ValidationGroup %>'
```

However for the second one to work you have to call `DataBind()` from code behind every time.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity what does DataBind() bind in this case?

Comment: Without it the value of `ValidationGroup` will not be bound to the Validator. That step is always necessary when binding data to controls that are not in a Repeater, GridView etc.

Comment: Adding the DataBind() worked. As EmptyWaterHoles said, would you care to explain what it does and why that makes it work. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. That is interesting

Comment: @MrSmith. I've explained a little already in my reply to @EmptyWaterHoles. But if you want to add a code behind value to a control, aspnet wants you to bind it explicitly. This is also the case in a GridView, Listview etc, but there you call it anyway otherwise there would be no data in that control (`GridView1.DataBind()`). And because DataBind is called in a GridView, something like this automatically gets bound `Text='<%# Eval("myColumn") %>'`